# Open text file using pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ascii, txt

I´m struggling to open a text file using pandas.
I have this dataset from an experiment and it should be a 87x249 table.

However, when I use the pandas `df.read_csv()` command I get all the time a table which is 87x1. I tried to change the delimiters but I always get different tables of 87x1.

I tried to open the ascii file in excel and then save it as a csv. Then it worked and I got a nice table. But the point for me is to use the txt file directly.

[image]

Comment: can you open the file using a text edior (vscode, sublime, pycharm or even notepad) and paste a few rows here. might be a `tsv` or space seperated csv try`pd.read_csv(sep='\t')` or `sep='\s'`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Here it is. I tried those separators as well. With \t I get 2 cols instead



# Simple array suitable for numpy, matlab etc.
# [nrows=85, ncols=249]
0.000000000000e+00    1.563209840090e-10    1.924648778129e-10    3.235447128639e-10    0.000000000000e+00    1.550617239795e-10    6.275445111707e-11    3.269484144160e-10    1.301647406156e-10    0.000000000000e+00    0.000000000000e+00    0.000000000000e+00    2.128934231497e-10    9.434081971923e-10    8.532389728089e-10    1.605743970382e-10    0.000000000000e+00    0.000000000000e+00

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.